# Конвертирование массива байтов в изображение и показ его в контроллере Spring атрибутом

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, velocity

Как такое можно сделать, а конкретно добавить в модель атрибут с изображением. Читал маны в интернетах, не нашел ничего подобного, только на конфигурирование самого бина конвертера потока возвращаемых байтов в контроллере. Запись в базу совершаю так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public String add(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute Item item, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (itemService.findOne(item.getName()) != null) {
        return show(model);
    }

    try {
        item.setImage(file.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    itemService.save(item);
    return show(model);
}
```

Сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Getter @Setter
    private int id;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String code;
    @Column(length = 100000) @Getter @Setter
    private byte[] image;
    @Getter @Setter
    private float price;
}
```

И собственно говоря, как правильно добавлять в атрибут (`model.addAttribute("image", ????)`) изображение, а также выводить его в разметке (`<img src="$!image" ....`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/item/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public byte[] item(@PathVariable int id)
{
    return itemService.findOne(id).getImage();
}

<img src="/image/item/$itemOne.id">
```