# Как отправить картинку в байт-массиве через REST?

Tags: java, rest, bytearray

Итак, у меня есть картинка в байт-массиве.

Я делаю GET-запрос, по которому я должен её передать. На данный момент, после многочисленных поисков в интернете, контроллер выглядит так:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/file")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getTableImageFile() throws IOException {
        byte[] imageFile = service.getImageFile();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        httpHeaders.setContentLength(imageFile.length);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(imageFile, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Присылает белый квадратик. Есть ли у кого-то решение, как вернуть картинку в корректном виде?

UPD. Проблема оказалась в бинах.

Comment: В этой статье все расписано: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Конвертирование массива байтов в изображение и показ его в контроллере Spring атрибутом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787938/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-spring-%d0%b0%d1%82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось намного сложнее, но помогла ссылка Олега Марченко. Очень долго я мучался, пока не догадался добавить в конфиг `WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer` следующее:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(byteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
}

@Bean
public ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter() {
    ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter arrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
    arrayHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(getSupportedMediaTypes());
    return arrayHttpMessageConverter;
}

private List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
    List<MediaType> list = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    list.add(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    list.add(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    list.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    return list;
}
```

Без этого бина и конфигурации максимум, что Вы получите - это набор байтов прямо на страницу или, если через хэдеры укажете, что это картинка, маленькую картинку ниачом.

Далее, сработала одна из конфигураций, полученных методом перебора:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/file", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getTableImageFile() throws IOException {
        return service.getImageFile());
    }
```

Comment: Не понятно, что такое service?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас расширение файла всегда будет *.jpeg* то объявите в аннотации что данный метод будет возвращать использую **produces**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/file", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getTableImageFile() throws IOException {
    byte[] imageFile = service.getImageFile();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(imageFile);
}
```

В ином же случае можете делать через `HttpEntity<byte[]>` и `HttpHeaders`

Comment: не без этого, но вся проблема, как это обычно бывает со Spring, оказалась в отсутствии бина